error when trying to push in Visual Studio to save changes in the repository
Git failed with a fatal error.
Git failed with a fatal error.
error: open(".vs/proyecto_final_DSWI/FileContentIndex/93d15405-ad61-4527-bebb-537d3f1a07af.vsidx"): Permission denied
fatal: Unable to process path .vs/proyecto_final_DSWI/FileContentIndex/93d15405-ad61-4527-bebb-537d3f1a07af.vsidx
This error occurs when trying to push to the branch created by me.

Does this answer your question? What is vsidx in Visual Studio and why is it autogenerated?

I don't think you want anything in the ".vs" folder being part of your git repository.

hello, first of all thank you for your responses, just to clarify the issue I have is that I closed the project and reopened it, but I saw that the branch I created and the change I wanted to make got deleted, I will see how I can resolve it

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
